# For airlines that have "vowed to offer carbon-neutral flights" how do they say they plan to actually make some flights demonstrably carbon-neutral?

Tags: carbon-footprint, transport, decarbonisation, air-pollution, carbon-offsetting

CNN's June 20, 2022 [Boeing unveils new 777 'ecoDemonstrator' test jet](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/boeing-777-ecodemonstrator/index.html) includes the following sentence near the end:

> Many airlines have already vowed to offer carbon-neutral flights and explore alternative fuels to reduce pollution.

**Question:** For these airlines, how do they say they plan to actually make some flights *demonstrably carbon-neutral?*

Maybe I'm presumptuous, but implicit in my question is that amongst the PR for these future carbon-neutral flights there will be some level of transparency and accounting, but right now I'm just curious how they say explain that carbon-neutral flights actually exist, presumably without shifting the carbon impact to other flights.

---

Potentially related:

- [Impact of various travelling options](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/93/5824)
- [Emissions offsets versus avoidance: can they be compared?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9555/5824)

Comment: It was a tossup between asking here and asking in Aviation SE. I'm assuming they don't mean [this kind of flight](http://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/airlander-10-air-nostrum/index.html) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the first airlines to initiate [sustainability](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/about-us/our-company/in-the-community/sustainability-at-qantas.html) and [carbon neutrality](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/qantas-group/acting-responsibly/our-planet/carbon-offsetting.html) in it operations was Qantas.

It has a [Carbon Action Plan](https://file:///C:/Users/Ivan/Downloads/qantas-group-climate-action-plan.pdf), which includes things such as:

- Establishing [carbon offsetting schemes](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/about-us/our-company/in-the-community/sustainability-at-qantas/fly-carbon-neutral.html).
- Retiring some aircraft, such as Boeing 747s and Airbus 380s early.
- Commenced using [sustainable aviation fuels](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/qantas-group/acting-responsibly/our-planet/sustainable-aviation-fuel.html) (SAF) on some
  flights, particularly those departing California and London. SAF is
  made from sustainable sources such as used cooking oil, council
  waste, plant oils, and agricultural residues. SAF has the potential
  to reduce lifecycle emissions by up to 80 per cent compared to
  conventional jet fuel. It has also used biofuel.
- Removal of single use plastic items from its service.
- The introduction of plant based meals on flights.
- All Qantas buildings powered by 100 percent renewable sources.
- Commitment to net zero emission by 2050.

It has also documented its [commitment to environmental sustainability](https://file:///C:/Users/Ivan/Downloads/our-commitment-to-environmental-sustainability.pdf).

In terms of carbon neutral flights it appears the airline will try to use sustainable aviation fuels and "encourage" passengers to assist by paying more for their flights by paying a carbon neutrality or carbon offsetting fee which will be spent of forestry schemes the airline has "invested" in.

Comment: interesting, it sounds like a bit like a voluntary "guilt tax" for the rich :-)

Comment: @uhoh: not just for the rich, but the environmentally concerned as well. If they must fly.

Comment: Of the 7.75 billion people on Earth, what fraction not only flies regularly but has sufficient "spare change" to pay a realistic carbon tax on it? I think it's way less than half.

Comment: "this just in" [Carbon offsets alone won’t make flying climate-friendly](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/07/carbon-offsets-alone-wont-make-flying-climate-friendly/)

Comment: @uhoh: Thanks, I'm not surprised. A few days ago, this news item appeared, [Rex Airlines announces plan to retrofit existing fleet with electric-propulsion engines in regional trial](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-07-27/rex-airlines-plan-retrofit-aircraft-electric-motors-emissions/101272566). Instead of burning jet fuel, the electric motors will be powered by a combination of  batteries & hydrogen.

Comment: Cool! It will be interesting to see when testing with live, paying customers aboard actually begins; "But I expect that we'll be seeing this happening in this decade, which is something I would not have thought possible three years ago." Previous flights carrying large quantities of hydrogen [left some customers less than satisfied](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hindenburg_disaster.jpg).

Comment: @uhoh: Not to mention, hot under the collar! [Hindenburg Disaster in Color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7clAJJNsdmQ)

Comment: Strangely, I just last night found out where the expression "hot under the collar" may have come from - celluloid made from camphor! starting at `03:37` in Asianometry's [White Gold: How the West Broke Taiwan's Camphor Monopoly](https://youtu.be/VxWt36579Hg)

Comment: @uhoh: Very interesting!! I've some things today, thanks.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What Fraction of Sustainable Aviation Fuel (SAF) is Actually Used Cooking Oil? Is this fraction itself sustainable?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12404/5824)